# Search/Filter JStree by metadata

Tags: search, metadata, jstree

I was wondering if there was anything in place in jstree to filter a tree based on metadata.

Something along the lines of

```
var v = $('#treeSearch').val();
$(element).jstree(true).search(v);
```

but instead of searching based off the name I would want to search based off of some metadata value x.

```
var mData = $('#mDataSearch').val();
//Search code
```

Thanks for your help